# What are the moments of Kolmogorov Complexity for a Random Variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, computability-theory, it.information-theory, entropy

Given a random variable $X$ distributed under some computable distribution $P$ we [have](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/13/3/595/pdf),

$$0 \le E[K(X)] - H(P) \le K(P)$$

Where $H(P)$ is the entropy of $P$. I tried using Hoeffding concentration bounds, but they aren't very helpful here. Are there similar bounds for $E[(K(X)-H(P))^2]$? In general, is there any way to get information about the distribution shape of $K(X)$ or is that uncomputable?

Comment: How do you define $K(X)$ for a random variable $X$?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich I linked a reference in the question, the expectation is supposed to be taken with a finite sum. You sum over the sample space of X multiplying by probability. It's mostly suggestive.